# Print only once different strings in specific column and how many times it was found

Tags: bash, awk, sed

```
#id|lastName|firstName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed

13194139534963|Berty|Jean|male|1988-08-02|2012-04-02T08:33:15.012+0000|41.216.190.153|Google Chrome

13194139535544|Oliveira|Manuel|male|1984-10-31|2012-03-14T16:00:12.287+0000|109.71.166.230|Internet Explorer

13194139537327|Wei|Lei|male|1987-01-06|2012-03-13T03:07:51.899+0000|27.99.188.150|Internet Explorer

13194139539118|Alvarez|Monica|male|1989-10-17|2012-02-25T19:18:54.137+0000|190.169.213.242|Internet Explorer

13194139539746|Xu|Wei|female|1986-11-30|2012-03-19T23:16:12.495+0000|27.103.77.193|Firefox
```

Say i have this persons.dat file. I am asked to list all the browsers found once **SORTED alphabetically** accompanied with a count of how many users use it ( seperated with a space). How can i do that ?

Comment: add the expected output for clarity as well as the code you tried to solve this

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry i am new here, next time i wont rush it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only standard command line Unix tools:

```
$ grep -vE '^#|^$' persons.dat | cut -d'|' -f8 | sort | uniq -c
      1 Firefox
      1 Google Chrome
      3 Internet Explorer
```

First we filter-out comments (lines starting with `#`) and blank lines (`^$`) with `grep`, then `cut`-out only the 8th field (using `|` as separator), `sort` alphabetically, and count with `uniq -c`.

Or, if you prefer only `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'|' '!/^$|^#/ {cnt[$8]++} END{for(x in cnt) print cnt[x],x | "sort -k2"}' persons.dat 
1 Firefox
1 Google Chrome
3 Internet Explorer
```

Where we split each line into fields on `|` as separator, then count the number of occurrences of each browser name (8th field) with `cnt[$8]++`, but only for  non-empty lines and non-comment lines (i.e. lines not matching `^$|^#`). In the end we iterate over and print all browser names accumulated, additionally sorting the output on second field via shell invocation to `sort -k2`.

---

Additionally, to reverse fields (name, count), you can run the output through:

```
sed -E 's/ *([0-9]+) (.*)$/\2 \1/'
```

or, in the `awk` case, simply reverse fields in `print` (and sorting key):

```
$ awk -F'|' '!/^$|^#/ {cnt[$8]++} END{for(x in cnt) print x,cnt[x] | "sort"}' persons.dat
```

Comment: Can you explain what !/^$|^#/ means. Thanks a lot !

Comment: See my edit (both for order and awk explanation). But note that now you'll have a harder time parsing the output (if further needed).

Comment: If i run the last inversed awk it prints : 1rome
 1refox
 3ternet Explorer
but the normal one works fine. Why ? @randomir

Comment: Probably your input file contains DOS/Windows newlines (both `\n` and `\r`). You can either convert it to Unix format with `dos2unix`, or split records in awk on either of those (add `BEGIN {RS="\n|\r"}` in the beginning of your awk expression).

Comment: Just wow , i fixed it with BEGIN {RS="\n|\r"}. Thanks a lot !

Comment: `RS="\n|\r"` would make the solution gawk-specific but more importantly it's the wrong regexp for DOS line-endings, that'd be `RS="\r\n"` (or `RS="\r?\n"` if you want to handle either DOS or UNIX line endings) with gawk. Using `RS="\n|\r"` will create empty records between every `\r` and `\n` pair and can have other negative side-effects if your input can contain `\n`s mid-records (like exporting from Excel can produce). Since you're using gawk for multi-char RS though, you don't need the pipe to "sort" inside the awk script, gawk can sort the data itself.

Comment: @EdMorton, I didn't know regex in RS is gawk-specific, so thanks for the heads up. But I chose `RS="\n|\r"` on purpose, to cover *Unix, DOS and Mac*, just in case. And the extra blank lines are not an issue because they are already filtered-out by the main expr. Also, I used `"sort"` in my answer to avoid the gawk-specific `asorti` and stick to the POSIX awk.